# QPainter::drawPixmap() doesn't look good and has low quality?

Tags: qt, qwidget, qpainter, qpixmap, qt5.5

I'm trying to draw an icon(.png) inside a `QWidget` with `QPainter::drawPixmap()`
 :

```
QPixmap _source = "/.../.png";
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing);
painter.drawPixmap(rect(), _source);
```

but in comparing to `QLabel` (for example) and in lower size (19*19 in my case) the result isn't perfect.

What can I do?

****Edit****

`QLabel` with pixmap @ size 19*19:

[image]

My painting @ size 19*19 via `SmoothPixmapTransform` render type:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are setting the wrong render hint, you need `QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform` to get smooth resizing. By default the nearest neighbor method is used, which is fast but has very low quality and pixelates the result.

`QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing` is for when drawing lines and filling paths and such, i.e. when rasterizing geometry, it has no effect on drawing raster graphics.

EDIT: It seems there is only so much `SmoothPixmapTransform` can do, and when the end result is so tiny, it isn't much:

```
  QPainter p(this);
  QPixmap img("e://img.png");
  p.drawPixmap(QRect(50, 0, 50, 50), img);
  p.setRenderHint(QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform);
  p.drawPixmap(QRect(0, 0, 50, 50), img);
  img = img.scaled(50, 50, Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
  p.drawPixmap(100, 0, img);
```

This code produces the following result:

[image]

There is barely any difference between the second and third image, manually scaling the source image to the desired dimensions and drawing it produces the best result. This is certainly not right, it is expected from `SmoothTransformation` to produce the same result, but for some reason its scaling is inferior to the `scale()` method of `QPixmap`.

Comment: Thanks.i tried what you said  but the result is the same!

Comment: @IMAN4K how big is the original image?